# MySQL searching multiple columns efficiently (lots of rows)

Tags: mysql, database

Hi there, working on an internal IP address allocation database. I'm aware there are open source options out there, but would like to make my own from scratch. I'm wondering if the way I am searching is the best way, given that there will be 10000s of records to search through.

Table structure is as follows:

```
+-------------+------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| ipaddress   | rdns                         | comment          | modified            | rangeaddress   |
+-------------+------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| 192.168.13.37 | something.internal.doman | Networks NAT | 2014-06-16 14:52:29 | 192.168.13.0/24
```

User interaction is through a web front-end using PHP, search is done by either IP, range, DNS or comment as follows.

Form grabs search query and passes to PHP script as `$q`. Explodes as an array, does jiggery pokery so that it can be used as a "LIKE OR" loop and implodes edited array as `$searchterms`.

Example:

`$q = "test search term"`
`$searchterms = "%test% OR comment LIKE %search% OR comment LIKE %term%"`

Final search query is:

```
SELECT * FROM ips WHERE ipaddress LIKE '%" . $q . "%' OR rdns LIKE '%" . $q . "%' OR comment LIKE '" . $searchterms . "' OR rangeaddress LIKE '%" . $q . "%';"
```

Is this the best way to be searching so many columns, or is there a better way?

Thanks,

Oliver

Comment: read about full text search in mysql

Comment: @Michael - thanks for the response. It appears `ips` table needs converting to take advantage of FULLTEXT but contains constraints to `ranges` table, which contains detailed information about the IP ranges. Given that, is there another suitable method?

Answer (score 0):

1) Avoid using 'like' clause in where conditions. In that way ,db can only scan all the records ,instead of scanning indexes.

2) In order to improve performance without losing flexibility, you can split fields which maybe appear in where clause.
Take 'ipaddress' for example,  store four separated parts instead of a single string. Then ,parse and transform user's query string.

If someone wants to query "192.168.*", the final condition should be something like 'part1=192 and part2=168';

If someone wants to query "192.16*", the final condition should be something like 'part1=192 and part2 between 16 to 169'.

The more complex parse algorithm is , the more flexibility you can provide.

Comment: Thanks Frank, though won't getting into such complex algorithms cause performance issues when the table is >10,000 lines?

Comment: The more lines you have ,the more efficient your program will be ,and the more benefits you get.